# Add showing HTML page due WiX installation

Tags: installation, wix, bundle, custom-action

I have an issue with adding html show up in my WiX bundle. Have you any idea how to  make it?

Comment: Please elaborate this, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way i have resolved is using internal WiX dll `WixShellExec`

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[InputResourcesDir]index.html" />
<CustomAction Id="OpenHtmlPage" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='OpenHtmlPage' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Directory Id="InputResourcesDir" Name="resource">
    <Component Id="index.html" Guid="{EE71FB84-2328-474E-9E5C-A29D2AD6EFD5}">
        <File Id="filEE71FB842328474E9E5CA29D2AD6EFD5" 
        Source="$(var.project.path)/$(var.project.resourceDir)/index.html" />
     </Component>
</Directory>

<Feature Id>
    <ComponentRef Id="index.html"/>
</Feature>
```

but this way has a problem, bcs html page is opened by default application (Notepad, Sublime, Chrome etc) that obviosly maybe will not be a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Second way how u can resolve it is by open default browser

```
<Property Id="BROWSER">
    <RegistrySearch Id='DefaultBrowser' Type='raw' Root='HKCR' Key='http\shell\open\command' />
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchBrowser" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" 
      ExeCommand='[BROWSER] "file://[InputResourcesDir]html.html"' Return="asyncNoWait"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='LaunchBrowser' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Directory Id="InputResourcesDir" Name="resource">
    <Component Id="index.html" Guid="{EE71FB84-2328-474E-9E5C-A29D2AD6EFD5}">
        <File Id="filEE71FB842328474E9E5CA29D2AD6EFD5" 
        Source="$(var.project.path)/$(var.project.resourceDir)/index.html" />
     </Component>
</Directory>

<Feature Id>
    <ComponentRef Id="index.html"/>
</Feature>
```